# Problemas no SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

alguem ja passou por esse problema no svn

Uso o SVN no linux e o Tortoise no windows 10.
Commit falhou (detalhes a seguir):

```
Não é possível mover 'J:\familia4\4r_sis\.svn\tmp\svn-4A465EB1' para
 'J:\familia4\4r_sis\.svn\pristine\2a\2a59232ae65ddb932d4109a4682d7cdfd933c6da.svn-base':
Acesso negado.
```

Comment: Algo que acontece em alguns programas no Windows é receber um erro de "Acesso negado" por não estar executando o mesmo como Administrador. Você pode se certificar que está fazendo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pressione e segure ou clique com o botão direito do mouse na pasta
   "J:\familia4" e clique em Propriedades.
2. Clique na aba Segurança.
3. Na aba Nomes de grupo ou de usuário, selecione seu usuário
   para ver suas permissões, se caso não tiver altere e dê permissão.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo .